# SQLServer geography data type using PowerShell

Tags: sql-server, powershell-4.0

I am using Powershell 4.0 and Sql Server 2014

I have a Sql Server database table which contains a 'geography ' data type field. When viewed using SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) the geography values look like very long (40 Char) hex numbers, ie 0xE610000101C11FCF.....

I want to export certain records for importing into a copy of the same database. I am using csv-export and csv-import for this.

First I read a record:

```
$sqlcmd = "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE ID = 123"

$record = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $sqlcmd -ServerInstance $s -Database $d -Username $u -Password $p -MaxCharLength 8000 -QueryTimeout 0
```

The record contains an ID and a geography member. Using PowerShell ISE to view the record returned:

```
ID   : 123
Geo  : POINT (123.456, 11.22)
```

It seems the geography value has been returned as a POINT. The subsequent csv-export and csv-import/INSERT code handle this under the hood, EXCEPT for some very particular values.  This causes validation to fail since the target database value does not equal the source database value.

I'm guessing the conversion to/from POINT is causing the problem.

To solve this problem I think I should read and write the raw hex value of the geography data.
How can I write a SELECT statement which returns the original raw hex data?

Comment: What's actually returned is a `Geography` object, and the `POINT` you see is the result of converting that to a string. To get the raw value, you can use `CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), Geo)`, but that will not round-trip transparently -- some effort would be needed to convert the resulting byte array to a string, and back again when reading the CSV. You could circumvent this mess entirely by using `bcp -N` rather than an intermediate step through text.

Comment: Thanks @Jeroen.  I shall investigate bcp.  Also, what I need to do is identify where the error is being introduced- at the SELECT stage or the INSERT stage. I'll update this page with my results.

Comment: What is the goal of your export/import? Are both systems MSSQL? If so, have you tried good ol' `bcp` with the "native" format? I've found that it avoids a lot of de/serialization issues.

Comment: Solution arrived at. In the export code , where data is the Geo field : CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), CAST(Data AS VARBINARY(Max)),1) As DATA